# Unable to install freetds on RHEL7

Tags: centos7, rhel7, freetds

I'm attempting to set up php-mssql in RHEL7.  `freetds` is not available in the default RHEL repo, so I enabled `epel` as follows:

```
rpm -Uvh http://mirror.oss.ou.edu/epel/7/x86_64/e/epel-release-7-5.noarch.rpm
yum install freetds
```

That yields:

```
Error: Package: freetds-0.91-2.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libgnutls.so.26()(64bit)
Error: Package: freetds-0.91-2.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libgnutls.so.26(GNUTLS_1_4)(64bit)
```

RHEL installed `gnutls-3.3.8-12.el7_1.1.x86_64` by default.

Is there a way through the woods?

Comment: You can use `yum install epel-release` instead of using rpm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While not ideal, this seems to work.

```
rpm -Uvh http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm
rpm -Uvh https://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/el7/webtatic-release.rpm
yum install php56w php56w-common
wget ftp://rpmfind.net/linux/epel/7/x86_64/f/freetds-0.95.19-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
yum install freetds-0.95.19-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
yum install php56w-mssql
# success
```

Answer (score -3):

After epel installed,
yum install freetds-devel

Comment: This is obviously not the correct answer. Did you bother to read the question?